# How can I transform background image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want that whenever I load my screen , the background image should zoom in and then zoom out. How can I achieve that inFlutter?

Comment: Check [ScaleTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScaleTransition-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add this Initstate code that you need to animate page

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: new Duration(seconds: 3));
    animation =
    new CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut);

    animation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));
    animationController.forward();

    setState(() {
      _visible = !_visible;
    });
  }
```

And add it this one to your image widget

```
             new Image.asset('assets/images/background.png',
                width: animation.value * 250,
                height: animation.value * 250,
              ),
```